# Error: cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

I got an error

```
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements FragmentGetContextFix.FragmentGetContextFixEntryPoint,
                         ^
      kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super pl.beskidmedia.bm.viewModel.repozytory.model.Token,kotlin.Unit> is injected at
          pl.beskidmedia.bm.domainlayer.viewmodel.tv.TvViewModel(fetchHlsUseCase, �)
      pl.beskidmedia.bm.domainlayer.viewmodel.tv.TvViewModel is injected at
          pl.beskidmedia.bm.domainlayer.viewmodel.tv.TvViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [pl.beskidmedia.bm.MainApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? pl.beskidmedia.bm.MainApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? pl.beskidmedia.bm.MainApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

when i tried to provide my use-case to view model, here are my functions that should create use case invoke() instance that i want to use later in my view model

```
fun getHls(
    tvRepository: TvRepository
): Flow<List<Hls>> {
    return tvRepository.getHls()
}

typealias GetHlsUseCase = () -> Flow<List<Hls>>

fun fetchHls(
    tvRepository: TvRepository,
    token: Token
) {
    return tvRepository.fetchHls(token.token)
}

typealias FetchHlsUseCase = (Token) -> Unit
```

and here are my modules

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
class ProvideFetchHlsUseCase {
    @Provides
    fun provideFetchHlsUseCase(
        tvRepository: TvRepository
    ): FetchHlsUseCase = { fetchHls(tvRepository, it) }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
class ProvideGetHlsUseCase {
    @Provides
    fun provideGetHlsUseCase(
        tvRepository: TvRepository
    ): GetHlsUseCase = { getHls(tvRepository) }
}
```

and finally my view model

```
@HiltViewModel
class TvViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val fetchHlsUseCase: FetchHlsUseCase,
    private val getHlsUseCase: GetHlsUseCase
) : BaseViewModel() {

    val hls = getHlsUseCase().asLiveData(coroutineExceptionHandler)
}
```

I can't change my provide to binding (this is what i saw in different questions here) or at least I don't know how to do it. When I was implementing this into my project I was inspired by https://medium.com/swlh/functional-use-cases-f896f92e768f this article, but author show only how to implement view model (no interface or bindings). From what i understands dagger should use designated provide methods that I implemented in modules but for some reason it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so this was a tricky one cuz this problem is actually well known but it is hard to google if you don't know how to name it, this was resolved [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900)
In short all I needed to do was insert @JvmSuppressWildcards behind my typealias "classes" in ViewModel at the insertion point like so

```
@HiltViewModel
class TvViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val fetchHlsUseCase: @JvmSuppressWildcards FetchHlsUseCase,
    private val getHlsUseCase: @JvmSuppressWildcards GetHlsUseCase
    ) : BaseViewModel() {
```

putting this annotation behind private keyword did nothing that why i had problems with this :D